# Laravel Passport. Why can’t I create an access token?

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

When I execute login, access token is not created, in the log files I get the following errors:

> local.ERROR: The resource owner or authorization server denied the request.

and

> (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): The JWT string must have two dots at.

I made a request using the insomnia program and everything works fine there, the access token appears in the database

My function login:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $req = Request::create(route('passport.token'), 'POST', [
        'grant_type'    => 'password',
        'client_id'     => 2,
        'client_secret' => 'lvDjvx5UgzeYJxQMjjLMSFL3psqXj2iuw2xLL6Yh',
        'phone_number'  => $request->phone_number,
        'password'      => $request->password,
    ]);

    $response = app()->handle($req);

    if ($response->status() == 400) {

        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Н',
        ]);
    } else if ($response->status() == 401) {

        return response()->json([
            'message' => '',
        ]);
    }

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: 'phone_number'  => $request->phone_number, 
replaced by    'username'  => $request->phone_number,

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
public function login(Request $request)
  {
    $req = Request::create(route('passport.token'), 'POST', [
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'client_id' => Your client_id,
        'client_secret' => 'Your client_secret ',
        'username' => $request->username,
        'password' => $request->password
    ]);

    $response = app()->handle($req);
    if ($response->status() === 400) {

        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Н',
        ]);
    }
    if ($response->status() === 401) {

        return response()->json([
            'message' => '',
        ]);
    }

    return $response;
}
```

In model User

`public function findForPassport($identifier) {
        return $this->where('phone_number', $identifier)->first();
    }`

Comment: This is the same, I redefined username to phone_number in Model User.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure "password_client" column is true in database for the client you're using.

If it's a "personal_access_token" it cannot provide password grant_type response. They are used to get client_credentials grant_type response.

You can find that out in your oauth_clients table.

I hope the answer will help you

Comment: password_client was true. It is oauth_access_tokens